# vbscript to download password protected google drive file - authentication failing

Tags: vbscript, google-drive-api

I have been working on a vbscript to download a password protected sheet from google drive as a tsv.  I know most of my code works because I use it to download files that are not protected from google drive as well as password protected files from another site (the other site has been removed from my code sample).

I know the google email and password are correct because when I copy them from my code to a browser session I can log in. - I removed the user name and password from my code to protect myself.  The response I get back from google is email and password do not match.  What am I missing?

*EDIT 3/4/16*

I'm not sure how to cut down on the code as it is all interconnected for anyone wishing to try to run it.  I bumped up the two new/edited functions, that is the likely source of the problem, to the top (fParseGoogleLogin and fParseRedirect).  fParseRedirect is called by fGetDataFromURL on picking up on an HTTP status 302 response.

*Code notes 3/4/16*

This pre-assumes that  the folder c:\users*username*\appdataroaming\pdiList already exists

You will need to use your own google username (strGoogleEmail), password (strGooglePass), and file (urlMainTable) for testing.  I left a value in urlMainTable for reference but it does contain sensitive data that cannot be shared outside of my company.

The sWriteWebData sub kicks everything off - passing the url to fGetDataFromURL and writing the final file to disc.

fGetDataFromURL passes off to other functions for reading (fLoadCookies) and writing cookies (fParseResponseForCookies) and handling redirets (fParseRedirect)

Again the problem I'm having is that with this code I'm getting back a page that says my password doesn't match the email address.  But the username and password work when copied from this code to the login pages in a web browser.

```
OPTION EXPLICIT
DIM urlMainTable, nameMainTable, strGoogleEmail, strGooglePass
strGoogleEmail = 
strGooglePass=

urlMainTable = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OCdhjjRSE4QsrngH0LJzM6IaFU1ZFpl9DZSjdINotYg/export?format=tsv&id=1OCdhjjRSE4QsrngH0LJzM6IaFU1ZFpl9DZSjdINotYg&gid=1439665763"

nameMainTable = "MainTable.tsv"

sWriteWebData urlMainTable, nameMainTable

Function fParseRedirect(blobHeader)
  DIM strLocation, lenLocation, iLocationHeader, urlRedirect, startRedirect, endRedirect, bolGoogleLogin
  bolGoogleLogin = FALSE
  strLocation = "Location: "
  lenLocation = len(strLocation)
  iLocationHeader = InStr(blobHeader, strLocation)
  startRedirect = iLocationHeader + lenLocation
  endRedirect = InStr(startRedirect, blobHeader, vbCrLf)-startRedirect
  If iLocationHeader Then
    urlRedirect = MID(blobHeader, startRedirect, endRedirect)
    If InStr(urlRedirect, "google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin") Then
      bolGoogleLogin = TRUE


    End If
    fParseRedirect = fGetDataFromURL(urlRedirect, "GET", "")

    If bolGoogleLogin Then fParseRedirect = fParseGoogleLogin(fParseRedirect, urlRedirect)
  End If
End Function


Function fParseGoogleLogin(blobResponseBody, urlForm)

  DIM iResponseBody, dictPOSTData, strKey, strPostData
  DIM iEndDomain, urlFormPost, bolSubmitAgain, blobResponse
  DIM iFormActionStart, strFormAction, iFormActionEnd
  DIM strNameStart, lenNameStart, iNameStart, iNameEnd, strName
  DIM strValueStart, lenValueStart, iValueStart, iValueEnd, strValue
  Set dictPOSTData =  CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  dictPOSTData.Add "Page", "PasswordSeparationSignIn"
  If (InStr(blobResponseBody, strGoogleEmail)) Then
     dictPOSTData.Add  "Passwd", strGooglePass
     bolSubmitAgain = False
  Else
      bolSubmitAgain = True
  End If
  dictPOSTData.Add "Email", strGoogleEmail

  iEndDomain = InStr(InStr(urlForm, "://")+3, urlForm, "/")-1

  urlForm = left(urlForm, iEndDomain)
  strFormAction = "<form novalidate method=""post"" action="""
  iFormActionStart = InStr(blobResponseBody, strFormAction)+len(strFormAction)
  iFormActionEnd = InStr(iFormActionStart, blobResponseBody, """") - iFormActionStart
'  urlFormPost = urlForm & Mid(blobResponseBody, iFormActionStart, iFormActionEnd)
  urlFormPost = Mid(blobResponseBody, iFormActionStart, iFormActionEnd)

  iResponseBody = InStr(blobResponseBody, "<input type=""hidden""")
  Do Until iResponseBody = 0
    strNameStart = "name="""
    lenNameStart = len(strNameStart)
    iNameStart = InStr(iResponseBody, blobResponseBody, strNameStart) + lenNameStart
    iNameEnd = InStr(iNameStart, blobResponseBody, """") - iNameStart
    strName = Mid(blobResponseBody, iNameStart, iNameEnd)
    strValueStart = "value="""
    lenValueStart = len(strValueStart)
    iValueStart = InStr(iResponseBody, blobResponseBody, strValueStart) + lenValueStart
    iValueEnd = InStr(iValueStart, blobResponseBody, """") - iValueStart
    strValue = Mid(blobResponseBody, iValueStart, iValueEnd)

    dictPOSTData.Add strName, strValue
    iResponseBody = InStr(iValueStart, blobResponseBody, "<input type=""hidden""")
  Loop
  iResponseBody = InStr(blobResponseBody, "<input id=""profile-information""")
  Do Until iResponseBody = 0
    strNameStart = "name="""
    lenNameStart = len(strNameStart)
    iNameStart = InStr(iResponseBody, blobResponseBody, strNameStart) + lenNameStart
    iNameEnd = InStr(iNameStart, blobResponseBody, """") - iNameStart
    strName = Mid(blobResponseBody, iNameStart, iNameEnd)
    strValueStart = "value="""
    lenValueStart = len(strValueStart)
    iValueStart = InStr(iResponseBody, blobResponseBody, strValueStart) + lenValueStart
    iValueEnd = InStr(iValueStart, blobResponseBody, """") - iValueStart
    strValue = Mid(blobResponseBody, iValueStart, iValueEnd)

    dictPOSTData.Add strName, strValue
    iResponseBody = InStr(iValueStart, blobResponseBody, "<input id=""profile-information""")
  Loop 
  For Each strKey in dictPOSTData
    strPOSTData = strPOSTData & strKey &"="& dictPOSTData(strKey) &"&"
  Next
  strPOSTData = Left(strPOSTData, len(strPOSTData)-1)

  If bolSubmitAgain Then  
     blobResponse = fParseGoogleLogin(fGetDataFromURL(urlFormPost, "POST", strPOSTData), urlFormPost)
  Else

    blobResponse = fGetDataFromURL(urlFormPost, "POST", strPOSTData)
  End If
  fParseGoogleLogin = blobResponse
End Function
Sub sWriteWebData(strURL, strWriteFile)
    DIM strData, objFSO, objTSVFile
    strData = fGetDataFromURL(strURL, "GET", "")
    If strData <> "DLFail" Then
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objTSVFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strWriteFile, TRUE)
        objTSVFile.Write(strData)
        objTSVFile.Close
    End If
End Sub

Function fLoadCookies(strRequestURL)
    DIM objFSO
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    DIM objShell
    Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    DIM pathAppDataRoaming, pathPDIListData
    pathAppDataRoaming=objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
    pathPDIListData = pathAppDataRoaming & "\PDIList"

    DIM fileCookies, strResponseDomain, pathCookieFile

    strResponseDomain = fGetDomain(strRequestURL)
    pathCookieFile = pathPDIListData & "\" & strResponseDomain & ".txt"

    If NOT  objFSO.FileExists(pathCookieFile) Then Exit Function

    Set fileCookies = objFSO.OpenTextFile(pathCookieFile)
    DIM dictCookies, strCookie, strCookieKey
    Set dictCookies = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Do While NOT fileCookies.AtEndOfStream
        strCookie = fileCookies.ReadLine
        If len(strCookie) > 1 Then
            strCookieKey = fGetCookieKey(strCookie)
            dictCookies.Add strCookieKey, strCookie
        End If
    Loop
    Set fLoadCookies = dictCookies
End Function

Function fGetDomain(strURL)

    DIM nEndDomain, strHost, nStartDomain, lenDomain

    lenDomain= len(strURL)
    nStartDomain = Instr(strURL, "://") +2
    strHost = right(strURL, lenDomain-nStartDomain)
    nEndDomain = InStr(strHost, "/")

    If nEndDomain Then  strHost = left(strHost, nEndDomain-1)

    DIM objRegEx, matches, match
    Set objRegEx = New RegExp
    objRegEx.Pattern = "^(.*?)\.?([^.]+)\.(\w{2,}|\w{2}\.\w{2})$"
    Set matches = objRegEx.Execute(strHost)
    If matches.count = 1 Then
      Set match = matches(0)
      fGetDomain = match.SubMatches(1) & "." & match.SubMatches(2)
    End If
End Function

Function fGetDataFromURL(strURL, strMethod, strPostData)
msgbox strPostData
  DIM lngTimeout, strUserAgentString, intSslErrorIgnoreFlags, blnEnableRedirects
  DIM blnEnableHttpsToHttpRedirects, strHostOverride, strLogin, strPassword, strResponseText, objWinHttp
  DIM iCookies, strCookie
  DIM dictCookies

  lngTimeout = 59000
  strUserAgentString = "http_requester/0.1"
  intSslErrorIgnoreFlags = 13056 ' 13056: ignore all err, 0: accept no err
  blnEnableRedirects = False
  blnEnableHttpsToHttpRedirects = True
  strHostOverride = ""
  strLogin = ""
  strPassword = ""
  Set objWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
  objWinHttp.SetTimeouts lngTimeout, lngTimeout, lngTimeout, lngTimeout
  objWinHttp.Open strMethod, strURL
  If strMethod = "POST" Then
    objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", _
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  End If
  If IsObject(fLoadCookies(strURL)) Then
    Set dictCookies = fCheckCookiesExpired(fLoadCookies(strURL))
    DIM itemsDict, bolDomainPathOK
    itemsDict = dictCookies.Items
    For iCookies = 0 To dictCookies.Count -1 ' Iterate the array.
        bolDomainPathOK = TRUE
        strCookie = itemsDict(iCookies)
        If InStr(strCookie, ";") Then
          bolDomainPathOK = fBolDomainPathOK(strCookie, strURL)
          strCookie = Left(strCookie, InStr(strCookie, ";")-1)
        End If
        If bolDomainPathOK Then objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Cookie", strCookie ' Set the Cookie into the request headers
    Next
  End If
  If strHostOverride <> "" Then
    objWinHttp.SetRequestHeader "Host", strHostOverride
  End If
  objWinHttp.Option(0) = strUserAgentString
  objWinHttp.Option(4) = intSslErrorIgnoreFlags
  objWinHttp.Option(6) = blnEnableRedirects
  objWinHttp.Option(12) = blnEnableHttpsToHttpRedirects
  If (strLogin <> "") And (strPassword <> "") Then
    objWinHttp.SetCredentials strLogin, strPassword, 0
  End If    
  On Error Resume Next
  objWinHttp.Send(strPostData)
  If Err.Number = 0 Then

    Set dictCookies = fParseResponseForCookies(objWinHttp.GetAllResponseHeaders, strURL, dictCookies)

    If objWinHttp.Status = "200" Then
      On Error GoTo 0
      fGetDataFromURL = objWinHttp.ResponseText
    ElseIf objWinHTTP.Status = "302" Then
      On Error GoTo 0
      fGetDataFromURL = fParseRedirect(objWinHTTP.GetAllResponseHeaders)
    Else
      fGetDataFromURL = "HTTP " & objWinHttp.Status & " " & _
      objWinHttp.StatusText
    End If
  Else
    fGetDataFromURL = "Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Source & " " & _
      Err.Description
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0

End Function


Function fBolDomainPathOK(strCookie, urlRequest)
  If InStr(urlRequest, "?") Then
    urlRequest = Left(urlRequest, InStr(urlRequest, "?")-1)
  End If

  DIM strDomainStart, lenDomainStart, strDomain
  DIM startDomain, endDomain, iDomain, bolDomainOK
  strDomainStart = "Domain=."
  lenDomainStart = Len(strDomainStart)

  iDomain = InStr(1, strCookie, strDomainStart, VBTEXTCOMPARE)

  If iDomain Then
    startDomain = iDomain+lenDomainStart
    endDomain = InStr(startDomain, strCookie, ";")-startDomain
    If endDomain > 0 Then  
        strDomain = Mid(strCookie, startDomain, endDomain)
    Else 
        strDomain = Mid(strCookie, startDomain)
    End If
    If InStr(1, urlRequest, strDomain, VBTEXTCOMPARE) Then
      bolDomainOK = TRUE
    Else
      bolDomainOK = FALSE
    End If
  Else
    bolDomainOK = TRUE
  End If

  DIM strPathStart, lenPathStart, strPath
  DIM startPath, endPath, iPath, bolPathOK
  strPathStart = "Path="
  lenPathStart = len(strPathStart)
  iPath = InStr(1, strCookie, strPathStart, VBTEXTCOMPARE)
  If iPath Then
    startPath = iPath+lenPathStart
    endPath = InStr(startPath, strCookie, ";")-startPath
    If endPath > 0 Then  
        strPath = Mid(strCookie, startPath, endPath)
    Else 
        strPath = Mid(strCookie, startPath)
    End If
    If InStr(1, urlRequest, strPath, VBTEXTCOMPARE) Then
      bolPathOK = TRUE
    Else
      bolPathOK = FALSE
    End If
  Else
    bolPathOK = TRUE
  End If

  If bolPathOK AND bolDomainOK Then
    fBolDomainPathOK = TRUE
  Else
    fBolDomainPathOK = FALSE
  End If

End Function

Function fGetCookieKey(strCookie)
  fGetCookieKey = left(strCookie, inStr(strCookie, "=")-1)
End Function

Function fParseResponseForCookies(strHeaders, strResponseURL, dictCookies)
    DIM arrHeaders, strHeader
    DIM objFSO
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    DIM objShell
    Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    DIM pathAppDataRoaming, pathPDIListData
    pathAppDataRoaming=objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
    pathPDIListData = pathAppDataRoaming & "\PDIList"

    DIM fileCookies, strResponseDomain, pathCookieFile
    strResponseURL = Replace(strResponseURL, ":443", "")

    strResponseDomain = fGetDomain(strResponseURL)
    pathCookieFile = pathPDIListData & "\" & strResponseDomain & ".txt"

    DIM strCookiePrefix, lenCookiePrefix, lenCookie, strCookie, strCookieKey, bolCookieObject
    strCookiePrefix = "Set-Cookie: "
    lenCookiePrefix = len(strCookiePrefix)
    arrHeaders = Split(strHeaders, vbCrLf)
    For Each strHeader in arrHeaders
      If InStr(strHeader, strCookiePrefix) Then
        lenCookie = len(strHeader) - lenCookiePrefix
        strCookie = right(strHeader, lenCookie)

        If fBolCookieDomainOK(strCookie, strResponseDomain) Then
          strCookieKey=fGetCookieKey(strCookie)

          If NOT isObject(dictCookies) Then Set dictCookies = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
          If dictCookies.Exists(strCookieKey) Then
            dictCookies(strCookieKey) = strCookie
          Else
            dictCookies.Add strCookieKey, strCookie
          End If
        End If
      End If
    Next
    If isObject(dictCookies) Then

      Set dictCookies = fCheckCookiesExpired(dictCookies)
      DIM itemsDict, iCookies
      itemsDict = dictCookies.Items
msgbox pathCookieFile
      Set fileCookies = objFSO.CreateTextFile(pathCookieFile)
      For iCookies = 0 To dictCookies.Count -1 ' Iterate the array.
        fileCookies.WriteLine(itemsDict(iCookies)) ' Return results.
      Next
      fileCookies.Close
    End If
    Set fParseResponseForCookies = dictCookies
End Function

Function fBolCookieDomainOK(strCookie, strDomain)

  DIM strCookieDomainStart, lenCookieDomainStart, strCookieDomain
  DIM startCookieDomain, endCookieDomain, iCookieDomain, bolCookieDomainOK
  strCookieDomainStart = "Domain=."
  lenCookieDomainStart = Len(strCookieDomainStart)

  iCookieDomain = InStr(1, strCookie, strCookieDomainStart, VBTEXTCOMPARE)

  If iCookieDomain Then
    startCookieDomain = iCookieDomain+lenCookieDomainStart
    endCookieDomain = InStr(startCookieDomain, strCookie, ";")-startCookieDomain
    If endCookieDomain > 0 Then  
        strCookieDomain = Mid(strCookie, startCookieDomain, endCookieDomain)
    Else 
        strCookieDomain = Mid(strCookie, startCookieDomain)
    End If
    If InStr(1, strCookieDomain, strDomain, VBTEXTCOMPARE) Then
      bolCookieDomainOK = TRUE
    Else
      bolCookieDomainOK = FALSE
    End If
  Else
    bolCookieDomainOK = TRUE
  End If

  fBolCookieDomainOK = bolCookieDomainOK
End Function

Function fCheckCookiesExpired(dictCookies)
  DIM strExpires, iExpires, dtExpires, lenExpires
  DIM strCookie, key, bolSession, startDT, endDT
  strExpires= "Expires="
  lenExpires = Len(strExpires)

    For Each key in dictCookies
      strCookie = dictCookies(key)
      iExpires = InStr(strCookie, strExpires)
      If iExpires Then
        startDT = iExpires+lenExpires
        endDT = InStr(startDT, strCookie, ";")-startDT
        If endDT > 0 Then  
            dtExpires = Mid(strCookie, startDT, endDT)
        Else 
            dtExpires = Mid(strCookie, startDT)
        End If
        If InStr(dtExpires, "GMT") Then
          dtExpires = dateTimeFromRFC1123(dtExpires)
          bolSession = False
        Else 
          bolSession = True
        End If
        If DateDiff("S", dtExpires, now()) > 0 Then
          dictCookies.Remove(key)
        ElseIf bolSession Then
          strCookie = Replace(strCookie, dtExpires, DateAdd("N", 10, Now()))
          dictCookies.Item(key) = strCookie
        End If
      Else
        strCookie = strCookie & "; Expires=" & DateAdd("N", 10, Now())
        dictCookies.Item(key) = strCookie
      End If
   Next
   Set fCheckCookiesExpired = dictCookies
End Function

function dateTimeToRFC1123 (dt_dateTime)
  dim a_shortDay, a_shortMonth
  dt_dateTime = dateAdd ("N", createObject ("WScript.Shell").regRead ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias") , dt_dateTime)
  a_shortDay = array ("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat")
  a_shortMonth = array ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
  dateTimeToRFC1123 = a_shortDay (weekDay (dt_dateTime) - 1) & ","
  dateTimeToRFC1123 = dateTimeToRFC1123 & " " & right ("0" & day (dt_dateTime) , 2) & " " & a_shortMonth (month (dt_dateTime) - 1) & " " & year (dt_dateTime)
  dateTimeToRFC1123 = dateTimeToRFC1123 & " " & right ("0" & hour (dt_dateTime) , 2) & ":" & right ("0" & minute (dt_dateTime) , 2) & ":" & right ("0" & second (dt_dateTime) , 2) & " GMT"
end function

function dateTimeFromRFC1123 (s_dateTime)
  dateTimeFromRFC1123 = cdate (mid (s_dateTime, 6, len (s_dateTime) - 9) )
  dateTimeFromRFC1123 = dateAdd ("N", - createObject ("WScript.Shell").regRead ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias") , dateTimeFromRFC1123)
end function
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to a minimum. It makes it easier to help.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the code above again today and it worked - must have been something getting cached somewhere.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I finally found the source of the wierdness - when writing my code I always assumed the values being passed into the various functions and subs were ByVal and treated them as such - sometimes this would throw things off as they were (by default being passed as ByRef - If anyone uses this code be sure to change all of the paramaters to ByVal